# How to import videos on my unity 2D game

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a 2D game yet we wanted to put videos, by using movieTextures of course we can upload or import videos but it will not build on the android phone. So my question is it is possible to put a 3D object to my 2D game? Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

i hardly can understand your question but generally you asked using a 3d object in a 2d game?

unity even for making a 2d game uses 3d space. but uses orthographic camera for 2d game instead of perspective camera that uses for 3d games. so simply you can use both 2d and 3d contents to your game. for better answer give more information.

Comment: actually my game is made in 2D and my professor wanted to add some videos, and so I've been searching lately and then videos can be embedded through 3D objects. Since I'm new I wanted to clarify if 3D objects can also be added to 2D games :)

Comment: and in movietextures in unity it can't be build on phones that's why I'm also making an alternative way :(